# how do i find the resistance R in this? I tried using kvl and kcl but still not able to find the answer

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, mesh-analysis

[image: Circuit diagram of the question from my course]

I have tried it with kcl and kvl but not getting the answer.
Then i tried with mesh analysis.But no good.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your work. (But I'd recommend to try node analysis instead of mesh)

Comment: I doubt anyone will *do* the question for you but they will correct your approach if you write it out

Comment: That's a nasty diagram. It doesn't appear to have a solution unless that 'wires crossing' place is actually a '4-way wires connecting node' without a dot. Ugh, horrible.

Comment: @Neil_UK In your way of viewing, there is missing another dot: where the 5 ohm connects with the 15 ohm and the unknown resistor. I think you can therefore conclude these points are interconnected

Comment: I have given an answer/explanation to your OTHER question of similar nature, and a few points made there should help you solve this kind of problems. If you take all the advice I gave you, you should already be 2 steps ahead. This is clearly a homework assignment and you are peppering this site with your homework problems while not taking the time to show us in detail what you did or tried so far, or the method REQUIRED for this. Why expect us to provide detail in an answer to YOUR problem, when you yourself don't want to invest more time and write all your steps and attempts in more detail?

Comment: Apparently, these are homework assignments requiring the use of Kirchhoff's equations, but you haven't mentioned that either. You only mentioned trying to use them, not that they are required.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a homework assignment.  I know you probably have a dozen of these to do tonight (I remember well   LOL).   I'll help with this one, but only to get you started.   You gotta puzzle these out yourself, only way to really learn it.

Every resistor has an "E", an "I" and an "R".  3 values that define what it's doing in the circuit.   It's like Soduko, you just keep filling in numbers you can derive or deduce, and they'll help you fill in other numbers.

The 15 ohm resistor is where you start.

You know there's 30V across this 15 ohm, so there's 
E=IR ->  I=E/R ->  I=30/15 -> I=2A
The 15-ohm resistors situation is now fully defined

Since there's 2A in the 15 ohm resistor, there must also be 2A flowing in the unknown R.  (They're in series).  So we have one of the 3 values for it.   You just need to figure out the voltage across it, right?

Next figure out how much current flows in the 5 ohm.   There's 5A coming from the left, there's 2A coming from the loop, KCL tells you 7A must be flowing in that 5 ohm resistor.

Again, ohms law...

E=IR  ->  E=7*5 ->  E=35V

Now you have the voltages dropped on the 15-ohm, and the 5-ohm.  They are 30 & 35V.   KVL will tell you now the voltage on the unknown R....   100-(30+35)=35V

This means you have E (35V) and I (2A) on the unknown R.

You should be able to take it from there   ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton dude! These weren t my assignment question or anything but past paper question from my university.Since they dont provide solutions to it and i am poor in electronics,i asked for help.You seem to have given me an awesome approach: that every element in a circuit has that "E","R","I" value... i am using it for many problems and taught my friends too.I cannot upvote as my credits are below 15 Thanks a lot!